# Get the value of the radio button that was selected before the user selects a new one

Tags: jquery, radio-button

If I have 3 radio buttons, is there a way through jQuery of finding out the value of the  one that was selected before the user clicks a new one?

```
<div id="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radios" value="1" checked="true" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radios" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radios" value="3" />
</div>
```

In the example avove, if the user clicks on `radio-3`, I need a way to get `1`, so that I can carry out some formattion to it. Thanks.

Comment: Save the value in some variable when user clicks it,, this way you can have previous value for next click

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would save the pressed values to an array and edit hidden value with that.

http://jsfiddle.net/BQDdJ/6/

HTML

```
<div id="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radios" value="1" checked="true" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radios" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radios" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" id="radio-previous" name="radio-previous" />
</div>​
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicks = new Array();
    clicks[0] = 1 //this should be the default value, if there is one

    $('input[name$="radios"]').change(function(){
       clicks.push($(this).val()) 
       $('#radio-previous').val(clicks[clicks.length-2])
    })
})
```

​

Comment: Instead of `clicks[0] = 1` you can do `clicks[0] = $('input[name="radios"][checked="true"]').val();` which will return the default value without hard-coding it in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 28):

You can use `mouseup` and `change` event. In mouse up you will get the value of `radio` button that is selected before selecting other radion button and change event will give the new selection of `radio` button.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DYrW3/1/)**

```
$('input[name=radios]').mouseup(function(){
    alert("Before change "+$('input[name=radios]:checked').val());
}).change(function(){
    alert("After change "+$('input[name=radios]:checked').val());
})​;
```

Comment: Great answer, +1. However is reacts in strange ways when clicking directly on the radio button and the option above (although doesn't deal directly with DOM events) is cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

"It's been a while" would be an euphemism but in case someone stumbles upon this issue:

[Adil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11052752/4770813) pointed me in the right direction, however `mouseup` only works for mouse-triggered events (duh), so I tried with `focus` and, since it also *happens* before `change` event, it works with, both, mouse and keyboard inputs (like when you change the radios status using the **tab** and **arrow** keys). So to gain access to the previously selected/checked item before the user interaction you use `focus` and to get the current item you use your good old `change`:

```
//html
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radios" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radios" value="2" />

//js
    //if currently checked item is radio-1
    $('[name=radios]').on('focus', function() {
        console.log($('[name="radios"]:checked').val()); //outputs 1
    });
    $('[name=radios]').change(function() {
        console.log($('[name="radios"]:checked').val()); //outputs 2
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying to make a budget calculator with options, I solved it using a a var to hold the last value;

```
            var before = -1;
            $('input:checkbox, input:radio').click(function() {
                // +(str) =  number(str)
                var value = +$(this).val();
                if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                        total += value;
                    } else {
                        total -= value;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (before < 0) {
                        total += value;
                        before = value;
                    } else {
                        total -= before;
                        total += value;
                        before = value;
                    }
                }
                $("#sub-total").text(total * hourly_rate);
                if ($(this).is("[data-toggle]")) {
                    $("#" + $(this).attr("data-toggle")).slideToggle("fast");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete #Adil's answer, if you have radios with text, if the user clicks the text, the previousRadio doesn't get updated. You can use the following:

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="radioName">
   text
</label>
```

And js:

```
var $previousRadio;
var $inputs = $('input[name=radioName]');
$inputs.parents("label").mouseup(function () {
    $previousRadio = $inputs.filter(':checked');
});
$inputs.change(function () {
    alert($previousRadio.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ville answer is correct for radio, here is for checkbox

```
<div id="radio-group">
    <input type="checkbox" id="radio-1" name="radios" value="1" data-prev="false" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="radio-2" name="radios" value="2" data-prev="false" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="radio-3" name="radios" value="3" data-prev="false" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('body').on("click", "[name='checkbox']", function () {
    $(this).attr("data-prev", this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Small hack. Add old value of radio button selected before to values of radio buttons like this.

```
<div id="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radios" value="1|1" checked="true" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radios" value="1|2" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radios" value="1|3" />
</div>
```

In attribute like **value="1|3"** first data is old value, second data is new value. Values are separated by '|' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking through this all and here's my take on this.  Just save off the information you need within the `Unchecked` event. radio buttons can only have one event checked so on uncheck you will be delivered the element that was last checked.  You can save that as a `RadioButton previouslyChecked` and read off information from that in the checked event.