# jQuery: detect radio buttons changes (which selected and which unselected) even if form field is hidden

Tags: jquery, radio-button

In a set of radio buttons I need to detect both radio selected and which one is (automatically) unselected.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/w562e0m1/31/) a simple example:

```
<div class="radio-container">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="radio1" class="hidden-field">
  <label for="radio1">Label 1</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="radio2" class="hidden-field">
  <label for="radio2">Label 2</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" id="radio3" class="hidden-field">
  <label for="radio3">Label 3</label>
</div>
```

Inspired by [solutions explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052702/get-the-value-of-the-radio-button-that-was-selected-before-the-user-selects-a-ne), I tried this JS code:

```
var field = $('.radio-container').find('.hidden-field');

$(field).on('focus', function() {
  console.log("Previous: " + $('.hidden-field:checked').next('label').text());
});

$(field).change(function() {
  console.log("Selected: " + $('.hidden-field:checked').next('label').text());
});
```

This works great but... only if radio buttons are visible!

If I apply the following CSS:

```
.hidden-field {
  display: none;
}
```

Detection of previous selected field does not run anymore (I tried also with `visibility:hidden` instead).

I need this because I'm using this technique in a very common "*CSS accordion solution*" in which label tag is clicked to trigger corresponding hidden radio-button.

Please, is there any workaround in js?

Answer (score 0):

Try `.on('change',...)` and get the checked value with `prop('checked')`